# Nginx doesn't resolve files with special characters

Tags: nginx, unicode

My wordpress has a couple of images uploaded that have special characters in their file names.

For example: `wp-content/uploads/2015/06/cambios-antes-y-después-de-hacer-ejercicio.jpg`

I see in  my `access.log` that nginx is looking for the file like this `GET /wp-content/uploads/2015/06/cambios-antes-y-despu%C3%A9s-de-hacer-ejercicio.jpg/ HTTP/1.1" 200"`

I do get a `200` response served by the wordpress `index.php`. But I don't get the file that I actually want.

The actual filename on linux is without unicodes `cambios-antes-y-después-de-hacer-ejercicio.jpg`.

My location directive:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: The URI being requested has a trailing `/`, which would cause `try_files` to fail to find it.

Comment: I have noted that as well, not sure where the trailing `/` is coming from though. If I curl the plain URL I get a 301 redirect response from nginx to the trailing `/` version

Comment: That `.jpg` is an image file and not a directory?

Comment: Of course, it's as well just an example. I got this problem with any image file that contains special characters

Comment: Is there a possibility that the Linux file system is not UTF-8?